# ¿Por qué pasa esto?

Tags: c

He realizado este codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
char current[256];
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[500];
    int i=0;
    char chr;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)!=NULL)
    {
        for(i=0; i<sizeof(line)-1; i++)
            if(isdigit(line[i]))
            {
                chr=(char)line[i];
                current[(int)chr]++;
            }
        for(i=0; i<256; i++)
            if(current[i]!=0)

        printf("Number:%c Times:%d \n \n",i ,current [i]);

    }

}
```

De esta manera hace lo que debe, contar numeros y mostrar el numero de veces que se repiten, asi como el número que es. Pero cuando añado `char current[256];` dentro de la función `main` el programa hace algo totalmente diferente.

¿Por qué es esto?

Comment: Hola Fran, bienvenido. Dices que hace algo totalmente diferente. Puedes explicar o pegar el resultado esperaro y el obtenido?  Un saludo

Comment: @FranciscoRoman si la respuesta soluciona tu problema te sugiero marcarla como aceptada para proporcionar más información a los que vengan después. Te recomiendo echar un vistazo al [tour inicial](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber cómo funciona StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si los arrays se declaran como globales o dentro de una función como estáticos:

```
char current[256]; // Variable global

int main()
{
  static char current[256]; // variable local estática
}
```

Se realiza una inizalización del mismo, en este caso seteando todos los valores a 0.

En cambio si el array se declara dentro de la función:

```
int main()
{
  char current[256];
}
```

Entonces únicamente se reserva la memoria necesaria para dicho array y la inicialización corre de tu cuenta. Por supuesto que puedes forzar dicha inicialización, pero tienes que hacerlo explícitamente:

```
int main()
{
  char current[256] = {0};
}
```

Como comentario adicional, dado que estás utilizando `current` para contar deberías plantearte usar el tipo `int`:

```
int current[256] = {0};
```

Además de poder contar más de 255 apariciones (que no creo que ese límite te vaya a causar un problema), el tipo `int` es más natural para operaciones numéricas, mientras que `char` está más pensado para la gestión de caracteres... cuestión de semántica.